# what is the buffer array doing inside the loop?

Tags: java, algorithm

can you please explain me this code? i am not able to understand the use of buffer array. how does value at every index become zero?

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String input1, String input2) {
        if(input1 == null || input2 == null || (input1.length() != input2.length())){
            return false;
        } else {
            int[] buffer = new int[26];
            for(int i=0; i < input1.length(); i++){
                buffer[input1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;  
                buffer[input2.charAt(i) - 'a']--;  
            }
            for(int j=0; j < buffer.length; j++){
                if(buffer[j] != 0) return false;   
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would answer your own question. After 24 hours (I think) you'll be able to accept this answer. And your comment does sound somewhat sarcastic.

Comment: Is this code working without exception

Comment: @janith1024 yes it is. actually, -a and +a is returning +1 and -1 , so it cancel out each other if the string is anagram, therefore the whole array becomes zero.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` holds a use counter for each lower-case character value used in the strings, all zero initially.

Each counter is then incremented for each use of a character in `input1`, decremented for each use of a character in `input2`, so if all characters are used the same number of times, all counters will become zero in the end.

This function will likely crash if called with strings that have anything but lower case letters in them.

Comment: i figured it out. but appreciate the help. thankyou so much.